# Android : part of the layout transparent

Tags: android-layout

I have a zone in my layout that I want to be transparent, while the rest of the layout has a black or an image in the background (kinda like a window effect). Is it possible in android?

Edit : Someone asked, so here is what Im trying to do :

[image]

The red part is supposed to be transparent, and there will be a movable widget in its place. The point is that when the widget move, what's behind the application appears.

Comment: Yes, just put a background image with a transparent part (it may be a 9 patch)

Comment: Feels a bit complicated. I need to put things over this backgrounds, in the transparent part and the black. Si I'd want the bacground to scale the same way the layout does.

Comment: That's why you use a background, not a src. And that's where 9 patches come in very handy!

Comment: Seems to me that a background image scale with the pixel size of the scrren, when layout scale with the densisty pixel, which give different behaviour according to devices screen. The size difference between the background image and others part of the layout does not stay the same when I switch device in the Android studio design section.

Comment: It seems to me that you didn't provide different resources, for different densities...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) on how to create a [transparent Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android).
After creating a transparent activity, make sure that every other component that you add to the xml (except for the zone you want to leave transparent) are opaque. (i.e. have their backgrounds set).

Comment: this does not work if I want to use an image as background

Comment: Image as a background of what? Could you please explain in a bit more detail of what you're trying to achieve? Maybe a diagram or a screenshot might help :) Cheers!

Comment: screenshot added in description